# Android VideoView prevent on video change

Tags: android, android-videoview, android-mediaplayer

I am using a VideoView to play Mp4 video. There are buttons in the screen and on the click event I need to change the video of the VideoView and play. I want this transition to be as smooth as possible. This is the code I was using in the button onclick handler.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName() + "/"+R.raw.myvideo);
mainVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);
mainVideoView.requestFocus();
mainVideoView.start();
```

I was testing this on my phone with Andorid 4, everything worked fine. But when I tested it in a phone with Android 2.2, I was shocked to see on click of the button the videoview part of the screen becomes black for a second and the new video starts. I cant afford that delay in my application.

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to live with that. I can't imagine any workaround that would completely solve this.

Comment: Oh is it a bug in 2.2 as it works fine in android 4.0 ? Any other workaround so that user wont notice it?

Comment: Well I wouldn't recommend it but it might be possible to use two MediaPlayers (note: not with VideoView). Or you can put something (like a still image) in between. And I don't believe it's a bug -- loading a video can take time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

This is a java code

```
package com.android.video;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;
public class VideoActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.main);
        VideoView videoView = (VideoView)this.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
        videoView.setMediaController(mc);
   //videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("http://www.mediafire.com/?trc33d4yma3rkv3.mp4"));
     videoView.setVideoPath("/sdcard/movie.mp4");
        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.start();
    }
}
```

This is main.xml

```
 <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <VideoView android:id="@+id/videoView" android:layout_width="300dp" android:layout_height="300dp" /> 
 </LinearLayout>
```

This is manifest file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```